# FTP image upload in android

Tags: android, ftp

How to upload image using ftp without Andftp installed in device.

My code :

```
Uri ftpUri =Uri.parse("ftp://yourftpserver.com");
intent.setDataAndType(ftpUri,"vnd.android.cursor.dir/lysesoft.andftp.uri");
```

Here in `setDataType` what i have to set.pls help me upload image using ftp..by creating folder,by renaming remote filename

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use a library for this:

Take a look at the Apache commons library:
http://lavalatwork.blogspot.de/2010/09/using-apache-commons-ftp-library-in.html

This might also be interesting:
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0404-ftp.html

Good Luck.